# LibGdx - Dispose Sprite or Texture in Sprite is mandatory?

Tags: android, libgdx

I am loading my sprite with the texture from my assets like I have mentioned below.

```
gameBoardSprite = new Sprite( new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/gameboard.png")));
```

Do I need to have the below dispose in my code ? Is it mandatory ?

```
gameBoardSprite.getTexture().dispose();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `dispose` must be called on any `Disposable` object before you lose your reference to it or there will be a memory leak. The VM won't automatically dispose of the native memory used by OpenGL objects like Textures so you must manually do it before you drop your reference and let the GC claim the "non-native" memory claimed by the object itself.

If you are going to use a Texture for the lifetime of your app, you might not be planning to ever need to dispose it, but on Android you still have to in the `Game`'s `dispose` method because there are cases where Android will shut down your Activity but not the entire Application so when the user reopens your game, all the previous textures are leaked.

Answer (score 0):

Well technically you don't have to dispose it, BUT not disposing it WILL impact your performance.

On android [Dalvik](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dalvik_%28software%29) will kick in and decide whether or not to free up some of your memory. Thus causing frame loss.

On your desktop, memory leaks may happen.

Read [here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Memory-management) for more information

Comment: I might be missing something but I can't think of any circumstance where performance would be affected. As long as you hold a reference to it, the GC won't collect it. Calling dispose won't affect whether that will happen or not. The dispose method is for cleaning up native memory stuff and must be done before dropping the Java reference or the native memory is leaked.